# Nerd on the Loose I - WHEN

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, science

**Chat.** I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18764/nerd-of-the-loose) in case anyone wish to discuss this further.

**Preface.** This is the first time I'm creating a puzzle. Since I find enjoyment in science and technology, the series of puzzles I'll be creating will revolve around such topics. I might provide warning as a form of hint when technical knowledge are required. Fret not, it would not be too advance. I hope you will enjoy solving them.

**Background.** Professor Swannie Taco is a genius in most fields of science and technology. She is probably hated by her parents, and her name is a perfect evidence. After Swannie went missing a few months ago, strange letters from her kept appearing on her G+ account. Nobody knows who exactly post these messages, nor understand the content of these seemingly cryptic memo.

**Clarification.**

> 1. For this particular puzzle, the only information required to solve it is the post.
>  
>  2. Knowledge of programming is not required. The necessary ideas are given as clues.
>  
>  3. At one part of the puzzle, some ideas are simplified. You'll know when you reach it.
>  
>  4. The "more" links on hints are for interested nerds who want to explore more. It is not required.

**Hints.**

> 1. She is knowledgeable in physical science and computer science.
>  
>  2. GNU stands for GNU is Not Unix. [More](https://www.gnu.org/)
>  
>  3. If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it might not be a duck. [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test)
>  
>  4. Since physics is fun, reciprocate frequently.
>  
>  5. Again, she love physical science, you know, like chemistry. [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_physical_science)
>  
>  6. SOH, CAH, TOA!
>  
>  7. To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)
>  
>  8. Imaginary number squared produces negative one. [More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number)

---

**Overview.** It was a few months after Professor Swannie went missing, when suddenly, she posted a riddle her G+ page, which seemingly tries to predict the doomsday.

**Post.** Definition of dynamite: Imaginary 66.7.95.53:52... For all cases, functions are not sensitive... Every iteration, a year went by... When the next struck, doomsday shall arrive... I shall overturn this world through my wisdom of science...

**Task.** Figure out the date of her predicted doomsday.

Comment: Interesting. Do my eyes deceive me or is that an IP address and port number?

Comment: Take a look at clue 4. Might help.

Comment: @A E It looks like an IP address and port, and port 52 is "Time Protocol". That might either be a huge coincidence, or it's a server you can somehow connect to.

Comment: Just a thought on the topic:
Perhaps 'imaginary' refers to the mathematical concept of 'i', meaning the square root of negative 1. Therefore maybe the IP Address lookalike is actually a ratio. Am I even slightly along the right lines? She wasn't a mathematician after all.

Comment: @crgsqdmn: that would fit with the idea that we're looking for a date/time as the answer. But I can't connect to that ip:port using telnet. Oh ok, clue 4, it's not an IP address. Maybe it's a duck? ;)

Comment: @ForIInRange You're on the right track for part of the puzzle.

Comment: Added hints (and background of the hints for those who are interested) and clarify up some stuff. Just remember, clarification are not hints, do not think about them while solving the puzzle, they will come to you eventually.

Comment: If she made the common "etymology = definition" mistake, we can look at the etymology of dynamite, from Greek dynamis meaning "power".  Next to "imaginary", we have an imaginary number to some power, or something to an imaginary power, which is helpful for getting back to real numbers.

Comment: i^66 is -1, i^7 is -i, i^95 is also -i, i^53 is i, and i^52 is 1. I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: 66,7,95,53,52 are the atomic numbers in the made up (imaginary?) chemical compound `DyNAmITe`.

Comment: @aschepler Interesting relation between "dynamite" and "power, although it is not quite what I am thinking.

Comment: @mdc32 Knowing powers of imaginary numbers is important in this puzzle, but you're heading towards the wrong direction.

Comment: @aschepler That is a great observation.

Comment: @aschepler I don't even want to know where you found that out. That's incredible.

Comment: @mdc32 I just went with "what if the numbers are atomic numbers?" and there it was.

Comment: "Every iteration, a year went by..." made me think of this: http://xkcd.com/505/ :)

Comment: @aschepler Yeah, actually that is what 4/5 of those clues are hinting towards. But some clues have multiple usage though.

Comment: Do you have a link to her G+ account?

Comment: @Mew The G+ account was prepared for future puzzle of this series, but I might be thinking of removing the usage of it. So yes I do have the link, but it was never required for this puzzle.

Comment: I've posted even more hints now, but those are just re-iterating some of the previous hints, but in more "obvious" wordings.

Comment: @nexolute - Why remove all those tags? Surely 'math' and 'science' fit even better than 'lateral-thinking'?

Comment: @randal'thor Was trying to remove the detective tag and replace with lateral thinking, accidently removed all. Added them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it in four years? 'When the next struck' I interpreted as 'when dynamite is dynamite again'. Every year the function is applied. After one year dynamite becomes i * dynamyte. after two years i * i * dynamite = -1 * dynamite. After three years i * -1 * dynamyte = -i * dynamite. After four years i * -i * dynamite = dynamite again.

Comment: You're on the right track... Just tell me the exact date. You can leave out the year if you want, but you can just assume its the day you're doing this puzzle.

Comment: Argh! You beat me by less than a minute! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor great minds think alike :)

Comment: I did get the answer independently though! I was in the middle of typing it up when you submitted your answer. I just beat you to put in a date though :-) But @nexolute - the question is, are we right?

Comment: Looking back again, I must say I didn't give much direction to point towards my expected answer, so I've decided to accept this. I was thinking about LEAP YEAR (29 February 2016), but it seems unreasonable to expect that from the way I phase my puzzle.

Comment: @nexolute: so how does 'LEAP YEAR' work? Just curious.

Comment: @nexolute - You could post an answer with your intended solution, just for interest's sake.

Comment: @randal'thor I will write one to explain everything now. In the meantime, I've already posted the second part of this puzzle. You can check it out. :D

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> 16 November 2018?

As @aschepler already noticed, the numbers give

> DyNAmITe,

so we have

> Definition of dynamite: Imaginary DyNAmITe. Functions are not case-sensitive, so (dynamite) = $i$*(dynamite). Iterate to get $i^2$, $i^3$, and so on. "Every iteration, a year went by" - so it takes a year to get from each power of $i$ to the next. To get back to where we started, we need 4 iterations ($i^4=1$), so 4 years from when the puzzle was posted.

I can't figure out how reciprocals and trig functions factor into this... It seems to fit all the clues except 4 and 6.

Comment: You're late by a minute. Great work though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my expected solution, which I did not reinforce it because I think I did not lead you properly to this answer. The spirit of the chosen answer remains the same.

Doomsday occured at:

> 29 February 2016

To figure this out, first realize that:

> The IP address is not actually an IP address, its just atomic number in disguise (hence the duck and chemistry hint). It will spell out DyNAmITe.

And then:

> Because its case-insensitive (from the actual post), dynamite := imaginary dynamite. Such definition is recursive (hence the bunch of recursion hint, such as GNU), we expand it. Look at the accepted answer for detailed explaination.

Finally, we link them all up:

> Most of the clue is trying to bring upon one word, period. Well, you might think period is a clue for periodic table, it is just a coincident (or is it), but it actually refer to the period in the math and physics sense. Every iteration a year went pass, so something with period of 4 years will be the leap year. Of course, leap year don't strictly occurs once every 4 years, hence the clarification I made that indicates I simplify certain stuff. Here is an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) to determine if your year is a leap year.

Comment: What about reciprocals and trig functions (hints 4 and 6)?

Comment: Reciprocals of frequency is period, and those trig functions are periodic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> There is no doomsday.

Explanation:

> As aschepler pointed out, The numbers refer to the compound DyNAmITe. If Dynamite is defined as negative DyNAmITe (ignoring case in the function not sensitive to it), the list will never iterate to the next value. It's a recursive loop. Doomsday will never arrive.

Comment: You got the case insensitive part right, and treating dynamite as a function is absolutely correct too. But dynamite is defined as IMAGINARY dynamite, not negative. You're on the right track through, answer is indeed a date.