# Nerd on the Loose II - WHERE & HOW

Tags: mathematics, riddle, science

**Preface.** Here is an relatively easy one, as compared to the [previous part](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/nerd-on-the-loose-i-when). We already found out when, let's find out where.

**Background.** Professor Swannie Taco is a genius in most fields of science and technology. She is probably hated by her parents, and her name is a perfect evidence. After Swannie went missing a few months ago, strange letters from her kept appearing on her G+ account. Nobody knows who exactly post these messages, nor understand the content of these seemingly cryptic memo.

**Clarification.**

> 1. For this particular puzzle, the only information required to solve it is the post.
>  
>  2. Although not strictly needed, knowing high school math will aid solving this puzzle.

**Hints.**

> I really don't think any hints are needed for this puzzle. This statement itself is **not** a hint in disguise.

---

**Overview.** Knowing when the doomsday is, we need to know where and how. Luckily, she told the whole world how, now we just need to know where. If only it was that

**Post.** Someone once told everyone that imaginary powers could sometime be real. Maybe if I could attempt to walk across all platform once and only once, thus performing a magical feat, I could break his claim, while justify his claim at the same time... Let's just say such a paradox shall distort the world, and it shall be where everything begins to end...

**Task.** Figure out where she is going to execute her doomsday plan. **Edit.** Since this was too easy, I will accept the answer that make sense of the whole "riddle".

Comment: 'HOW' - blow up [place mentioned by Ivo] with [substance found by aschepler]?

Comment: @randal'thor Actually its even more *nonsensical* than that, and it could be found in her post. She simply just want to create a paradox and distort the world. [Substance found by aschepler] could not possibly have that great impact to this world.

Comment: That might depend on how much of the substance you have!

Comment: So she's a bit of a nutter then? :-) (Is her name some kind of wordplay, btw? I hunted for something there but couldn't get it.)

Comment: @randal'thor She is indeed a nutter. As for who she really is, that we shall leave for the next part, yeah? Also, I've undo the acceptance of the accepted answer, because I expect a full explaination of how the solution links to the riddle. Hope that is not against any rules here.

Comment: 'who she really is' - some Puzzling.SE user perhaps?

Comment: If only it was that?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it in Königsberg? The walking across platforms just once sounds like the famous bridges of Königsberg problem. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg

Comment: Gosh, I knew this was too easy. It's okay, I'll try to make a tougher one next. But, could you link everything together?

Comment: @nexolute - so the 'he' in the question is Euler?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes. But how does everything links up?

Answer (score 2):

Interpretation 1:

> The first statement is a reference to Euler's argument for the existence of God. By doing a magical feat and possibly walking on the river, she proves that she is God, proving Euler's claim, but disproving his belief in logic, maths and Jesus.

Interpretation 2:

> The first statement refers to Euler's equation, formula on the exponential function. I, the imaginary number, walks around the bridges and somehow ends up justifying said equation, while contradicting itself once in a while.

Comment: Interpretation 2 is on the right track, and the only lacking part is the explanation on contradiction now.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Mobius strip?

Comment: No. Its all about what this person, which you figured out its Euler, did.

Comment: Your interpretations aren't showing as a spoiler. The >! needs to be on another line.