# Nerd on the Loose III - WHO, WHAT & WHY

Tags: mathematics, mystery, science

**Preface.** After the extraordinarily easy "[riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/nerd-on-the-loose-ii-where-how)", I guess I can wrap out everything in this "detective" puzzle.

**Background.** Professor Swannie Taco is a genius in most fields of science and technology. She is probably hated by her parents, and her name is a perfect evidence. After Swannie went missing a few months ago, strange letters from her kept appearing on her G+ account. Nobody knows who exactly posted these messages, nor understands the content of these seemingly cryptic memos.

**Clarification.**

> None.

**Hints.**

> None.

---

**Overview.** Feeling worried, you decided to do some detective work and check her past. You thought, which parents name their child "Taco", it is definitely fishy. However, no matter how much you dig, you just can't seem to find any record of her birth. It's like she just appeared into this world.

On her [G+](https://plus.google.com/116758574347391243190/) page, there are some information that seems valuable. You recorded them just in case. In the meantime, she posted her final message.

**Post.** It was believed that I "borrowed" ideas from him. It wasn't true, and I cannot accept the distrust from you mere mortals. Here is a final chance, let me have what is rightfully mine, and you homo sapiens shall avoid the avoidable death.

**Task.** Figure what who she really is, why she is doing all this, and what she really wants.

Comment: 'Parent name their child "Taco"' - so is Taco her first name or surname??

Comment: @randal'thor Turns out, it doesn't really matters. But lets just stick to convention and let it be her last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps she, as

> Isaac Newton

is upset with

> Gottfried Leibniz

because

> it is unclear which of the two created the idea of calculus (Newton's "fluxions and fluents") first, and Newton wanted full credit for the original discovery.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking of. In fact, Leibniz got much of the credits, and much of the people thought Newton plagiarised his work, and there was much [dispute upon that](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz–Newton_calculus_controversy).

Comment: I was confused with the 'she', as Newton is a 'he' :P

Answer (score 2):

It's probably wrong but, is Swannie Taco an anagram for

> Isaac Newton

What she wants

> An apple

And the girl is

> EVE (also a robot in Wall-E)

I found out that

> Isaac Newton died on 31 March, 1727. Maybe 1927 is not accepted by Google+

EDIT (new guess):

What she wants

> Recognition for E=MC², you could say she's pissed at Einstein!

And the girl is

> Emilie du Chatelet, she translated the principia from Isaac Newton

Comment: Sounds like you're onto something here!

Comment: Good job for figuring out the anagram. You're indeed onto something. Other than that, the rest isn't quite what I'm thinking.

Comment: I'm thinking about the object being the principia, but that might be a bit deep.

Comment: Great job finding out about the subtle hints of Isaac Netwon. The birthdate, the anagram, even the display banner (optics) and display picture (pixar->stevejobs->apple) is trying to hint about Isaac. I would agree he should be damn piss with Einstein due to general relativity, but definitely an idea Netwon "borrowed" from Einstein, since the chronological order will not match. Nice attempt though. Think back in history will sure help.

Comment: @Gudgip Its not that far from what I've in mind. You're on the right track.

Comment: Great! I'll keep on searching :-)

Comment: @Gudgip Here to help you save some time, the G+ is solely there to identify her true identity. Don't linger around there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a wild guess. Looking at her Google+ page i see she is born March 31, 1927. Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_1927#March_31.2C_1927_.28Thursday.29 I see that on that date also the actor was born who is the voice of Knightrider's KITT, an artificially intelligent electronic computer module in the body of a highly advanced, very mobile, robotic automobile. Reading in the **Post** that she refers to us as mortals I can imagine that she is immortal and that like KITT she is some sort of intelligent robot.

Comment: Nice detective work. Not quite what I have in mind.